# Status Bars and their Nature

Tags: design-patterns, status, user-communication

I want to know more about status bars, what are they useful for and what is the appropriate way to use them.

I've noticed the following:

- Status Bars are always located at the bottom with the most significant information in the rightmost side of the screen (**why?**)
- Status Bars are often disabled by default (**why?**)
- Is the concept of status bar lost while jumping from window-based applications to web, or is it just rendered differently?

I also want to know what kind of messages are appropriate for the status bar?

- Information that changes often?
- Modifiable Properties that change the behavior of the application (*Modifiers?*)?
- Modeless Progress Bars (Finite or Infinite)

Is there anything I should avoid as a best practice for a status bar?

An example of a status bar is displayed in the image below:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f86ff8.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

So pretty much what **I want to know is the dos and don'ts of status bars and how they can help enhance user experience.** The information above is to be taken as a reference only, so don't feel constrained to ask the questions in this description.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by status bar here ? Are you referring to a status bar indicator like http://www.prof-uis.com/img/tour_ff_img/ff_140_status_bar.jpg or are you talking about progress indicators

Comment: I'm talking about Status Bars. I'm considering that a status bar can have one progress indicator, for example...

Comment: Update your question with some examples so that people know what you are talking about

Comment: Served, sir! :)

Comment: I think this question is currently a bit vague. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Consider if this question were about tables. "What are the dos and donts of tables? When should I use them? When shouldn't I?" In that case, the question is too broad. They are a design pattern, and patterns are used in a variety of situations. It's better to read a design pattern library that goes into detail (or a book) than to ask a question here. If you have a specific question, like "Is providing a zoom control in a status bar a good idea" then consider asking that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A status bar, as per definition of the term, **communicates status**. This means, by default, reserve it for things that identify the state of the application rather than user actions. Though I can't offer a authoritive source, some things that come to mind:

**DOs**:

- **application status** (location, operational status, identifiers, cursor position, selected tool, ...)
- background **activity and progress** (saving, compressing, loading)
- clickable entries that open context menus for the above listed
- clickable options that are both descriptive of the application status as well as user modifiable (zoom, settings, notifications)
- consequences of user action, tooltip-like information (mouse hovering over a link in a web browser, for example)
- populating the status bar does not change its distinction to content (in look)
- optionally the status bar is only displayed when there is items to communicate or when change occurs

**DONT's**

- user actions / buttons / application tools
- menus
- inputs